# How to take unique values from mongodb aggregate pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My current mongodb aggregate pipeline output is

```
[
    {
        "CustomerID":"E001",
        "CustomerName":"Suresh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E001",
        "CustomerName":"Suresh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E002",
        "CustomerName":"Ramesh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E003",
        "CustomerName":"Kishore",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E002",
        "CustomerName":"Ramesh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E001",
        "CustomerName":"Suresh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    }
];
```

Actual response should be unique based on **CustomerID**

```
[
    {
        "CustomerID":"E001",
        "CustomerName":"Suresh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E002",
        "CustomerName":"Ramesh",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    },
    {
        "CustomerID":"E003",
        "CustomerName":"Kishore",
        "CustomerPhone":"919889902----",        
    }
];
```

I don't know what operator to use to get unique values from aggregate pipeline.

I am using $project, $sort  for projection of response and $skip and $limit for pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by the value you want :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $group:{
       _id: "$CustomerID",
       CustomerId: {$first:"$CustomerID"},
       CustomerName: {$first: "$CustomerName"},
       CustomerPhone: {$first: "$CustomerPhone"}
    }
  }
]);
```

I assume that name and phone are the same for the same customer Id, otherwise replace $first with $addToSet in order to get all names and phones

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982594 hi can you please answer my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982594/how-to-calculate-rank-from-total-points-in-aggregate-pipeline-for-gaming-applica/50989833#50989833